# Can I upgrade Chef Server 11.1.3 nodes to chef-client 12.5.1?

Tags: chef-infra

We are running Open Source Chef Server 11.1.3.

Can we upgrade our server 11.1.3 nodes to [chef-client 12.5.1](https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/10/08/chef-client-12-5-released/)?

Would anything prohibit me from making use of the new custom resource model in my cookbooks?

We do plan to upgrade to chef-server-core 12.2.0-1, but haven't finished testing yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When chef client 12.0 has been release the comaptibility with chef server 11 was said to work (I personally had problems with chef-server 11.0.8).

There's no compatibility matrix as far as I know.

If a chef-client 12.5 can work with your server, the custom_resource won't be a problem, the server only store cookbooks and don't run them, so it should be ok to use them in your cookbooks.

Edit to complete:
Quote of [this message](https://discourse.chef.io/t/does-a-compatibility-matrix-of-client-server-exists/7234/2?u=tensibai) from Kallistec on the chef mailing list:

> Each product is supposed to work with +/- 1 major version of the
>   other. Two caveats:
>
> - there will be bugs, so if there’s a bug in 11.0.8 and it’s not fixed    until 11.1.x, you would need to upgrade
> - When new functionality is added that requires both client and server to function, we don’t make any commitments about backporting.
>     For example, the new policyfile features aren’t going to be backported
>     to Chef Server 11.